# How to display imenu content in speedbar

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar, imenu

I would like to display imenu content in Emacs Speedbar. Best as a flat list (like in with `imenus`) (not a tree-like structure). 
In speedbar - Display menu I have only the following options:

- Files
- Quick Buffers
- Buffers
- Info
- Eieio
- Analyze (only after calling `semantic-speedbar-analysis`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scfrazer/.emacs.d/master/lisp/src/sb-imenu.el) for myself so there is no documentation, but all you should have to do is put it somewhere in your load-path and:

`(require 'sb-imenu)`

Start speedbar and choose the sb-imenu display.

Comment: Thanks. Works well. Do you know how to configure speedbar to use `sb-imenu` display be default?

Comment: To set it as the initial mode: `(setq speedbar-initial-expansion-list-name "sb-imenu")`

Comment: do you have a new version of sb-imenu? It seams that your snippet doesn't work with latest emacs.

Comment: @RobertZaremba, by latest do you mean 27?

Comment: I have 26.3; I solved the problem - I had to byte-compile the file, then the package works.